# Unable to create file in Google Drive with node.js and OAuth tokens

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-cloud-functions

Everything I've looked at suggests my code should work, and the logs in Firebase Functions console shows that it returns
`Function execution took 6 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`
I've based my code off this sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync
From which I get in the logs `Function execution took 296 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`

After I got the google-sheets example working, I basicaly copy/pasted it and change a few lines but no matter what I do I can't seem to get Google Drive working.

Here's the code I've come up with (if you check the google-sheets example you'll see how they're basically the same).

```
exports.makenewfolder = functions.database.ref(`${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}/{ITEM}`).onWrite(
      event => {
        // Since we're not dealing with the data from the DB, don't need the spreadsheets info
        // Just need to return the promise with auth included
        /*var fileMetadata = {
          'name': 'test folder',
          'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        };*/

        var fileMetadata = {
          name: 'Test',
          mimeType: 'text/plain'
        }
        return drivePromise(this.fileMetadata);
      }
    )

    function drivePromise(requestWithoutAuth) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAuthorizedClient().then(client => {
          const service = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: client });
          const request = requestWithoutAuth;
          request.auth = client;

          service.files.create({
            resource: {
              name: 'Test',
              mimeType: 'text/plain'
            },
            media: {
              mimeType: 'text/plain',
              body: 'Hello World'
            }
          }, (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
              // handle error
              console.error(err);
            } else {
              console.log('Folder id: ', file.id);
            }
          }    
        );
        }).catch(() => reject());
      })
    }
```

Why does this not work? It should be working because the SCOPE is for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` instead of `/auth/spreadsheets` so it shouldn't be able to modify the spreadsheet anymore except through the fact that the spreadsheet is in Google Drive. When I run the code which includes the rest of the code from the sample, the spreadsheet still gets updated. The logs show that these functions are being called, but nothing happens in Google Drive. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`return drivePromise(this.fileMetadata);` doesn't work apparently. `return drivePromise(fileMetadata);` does. Sigh.